# How to extend the source menu in Eclipse? (or: What is its locationURI?)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am developing an eclipse plugin and trying to extend the source menu (mainMenubar/Source - visible when editing in the java-editor) in Eclipse 3.7.

The [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Findex.html) says to rely on the `org.eclipse.ui.menus`-extension point since the older extension points are deprecated. It is a complete secret to me where to obtain reliable locationURIs, but I finally managed to find some plausible URI with the Plugin Spy (following an advice [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy_menu)).
So the following *should* be the extension snippet for the plugin.xml:

```xml
<extension
 point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
 <menuContribution
     locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.source.menu">
  <command
    commandId="some.command.id"
        label="Some label"
        style="push">
  </command>
 </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Unfortunately, when running the plugin for my development IDE no command appears, and also no error message. Just nothing happens. When I set the locationURI to "menu:help", the new command appears in the help menu, so the problem seems to be really the locationURI.

Comment: I believe that JDT adds the `Source` menu item to its `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CodingActionSet` action-set, which is probably enabled when you are in the `Java` perspective. Do you have your own perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. I finally figured out that extending the Source menu using the (recommended) extension point `org.eclipse.ui.menus` is not possible.

The reason is that a menu defined in an old style `actionSet` (like the Source menu) is created after the processing of `org.eclipse.ui.menus`-extensions. The way it is, these extensions can only contribute to already existing menus.

So sticking to the old API (as suggested by VonC) is probably the best option until the `jdt` plugin is migrated to the new approach...

Answer (score 4):

[This thread reports](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/82324/) having added an entry in the main Source menu:

```
<!-- main menu -->
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
  <actionSet label="Java Coding"
             description="Action set containing coding related Java actions"
             visible="true"
             id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CodingActionSet2">
    <menu label="&amp;Source"
          path="edit"
          id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.source.menu">
    </menu>
    <action class="org.gsoc.eclipse.tostringgenerator.actions.GenerateToStringActionDelegate "
            id="org.gsoc.eclipse.tostringgenerator.action"
            label="Generate to&amp;String()..."
            menubarPath="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.source.menu/generateGroup">
    </action>
  </actionSet>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `popup:` space instead of the `menu:` space. Here is a working example:

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command defaultHandler="com.igenox.plugin.dpbuilder.rcp.handler.CreateBuilderHandler"
        id="com.igenox.plugin.DPBuilder.CreateBuilderPattern" name="CreateBuilderPattern">
    </command>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.source.menu?after=DPSeparator">
        <command commandId="com.igenox.plugin.DPBuilder.CreateBuilderPattern"
            id="createBuilder" label="Create Builder Pattern">
        </command>
    </menuContribution>
    <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.source.menu?after=additions">
        <separator name="DPSeparator" visible="true">
        </separator>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```