# Eclipse plug-in: why doesn't my menu contribution show up after using a shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, plugin.xml

I wanted to add a menu item to the **Source** popup, and I got it working with the following `plugin.xml` fragment:

```
 <menuContribution allPopups="true" locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.source.menu">
        <command
              commandId="pl.axit.eclipse.bundle.commands.convertToBundle"
              id="pl.axit.eclipse.bundle.menus.convertToBundle"
              label="Extract bundle" >
        </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

And it works after I click the right mouse button and then select **Source** I can see my **Extract bundle** item. Great.

[image: Using the mouse, everything works]

But... when I open the **Source** menu with a shortcut (alt+shift+s) then my **Extract Bundle** isn't there! Any idea why and how to make it appear after using the shortcut?

[image: My item is absent when using the shortcut to bring up the Source popup]

Comment: It's rather an insanity check, but have you checked if the two popup menus have the same ids? You can use the Plugin Spy for that (Alt+Shift+F2). It looks like in the second case it is not a submenu. So maybe th ids are different.

Comment: For the menu showing up after using the shortcut, the 
active contribution location URI is 
"menu:null"... So yeah, it's different. But now what?

Comment: Hmm, from what I have read, the problem seems to be that the meun items are added by the old Action framework instead of the Commands framework. I am unsure how to add items to that one, atm. Maybe I find the time to play around with that over the weekend.You could try to start from there in the mean time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113380/how-to-extend-the-source-menu-in-eclipse-or-what-is-its-locationuri